# Concatenate list of string in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

Hello enthusiast programmers,
It seems I am very bad at manipulating lists in Python (I come from the IDL world, and I really struggle with Python). I have a list of string, say:

```
mylist =['boring', 'enjoyable', 'great']
```

and a string, say:

```
s = 'Python is '
```

and I want to build the list: ['Python is boring', 'Python is enjoyable', 'Python is great']

```
mynewlist = s + l
```

as I would have simply done in IDL, doesn't work of course ... I am not able to do it simply! (i.e. without a loop and intermediate variables)

Thanks for the help!

s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` or list comprehensions:

```
map(lambda x: "Python is " + x, mylist)

["Python is " + x for x in mylist]
```

Both solutions will do an implicit loop, just like IDL would; it is inevitable to have one in this scenario. But no overt loop like `for ...:`.

Answer (score 2):

that would be:

```
newlist = [s + x for x in mylist]
```

You basically carry out the same addition for each element of mylist; the result is a list itself. The way it is done is called list comprehension, one of the most powerful tools for list manipulation.